# Как загрузить клип вк?

Tags: python, python-3.x, вконтакте, requests

```
ay = {'access_token': token, 'v': '5.123'}
r = requests.post('https://api.vk.com/method/shortVideo.create', data=ay,
                         headers=headers)
```

Получаю ответ:

```
{'response': {'owner_id': 11111, 'video_id': 111111, 'upload_url': 'https://vu.mycdn.me/upload.do?sig=89ea737665b949045a9ae8f573f68fd22695b917&expires=1602828062932&clientType=13&appId=512000384397&id=2073322662253&userId=0'}}
```

Пытаюсь загрузить видео по ссылке из upload_url

```
upload_url = r.json()['response']['upload_url']
resp = requests.post(upload_url, files={'file': open('1.mp4', 'rb')})
```

Получаю ошибку 403 "HTTP Status 403 - Can't get file item containing data"

Comment: Так и не нашёл решенья проблемы?? я вот столкнулся с такой же проблемой ранее все работало отлично и вдруг перестало при чем при загрузке лишь в определённую группу в любую другую работает без проблем люди кто знает в чем дело подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Аналогичная проблема, сначала в одной группе блок на загрузку видео, потом в другой. Хз что делать, смена ip не помогает. Либо закручивают гайки, либо поломали апи.

Comment: кто ни будь разобрался как передавать Content-Type?

Answer (score 1):

я написал в тех поддержку вк это их баг вот что они ответили "Это связано с изменениями с нашей стороны. Разработчики обещали пофиксить загрузку, но пока что в качестве временной меры надо в запросе на загрузку передавать Content-Type вот в таком формате:" https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#multipartform-data

Comment: Я и до этого грузил мультипартом, он сейчас не работает, ответ всегда один:

Apache Tomcat/7.0.79 (ok11) - Error report
HTTP Status 403 - Can't get file item containing data
Status report
message
 Can't get file item containing data
description
 Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.79 (ok11)

Comment: я так понимаю что дело именно в python потому что <form action="https://ovu.mycdn.me/upload.do?sig=88e0f261752185cd36c1f96fd934701a80860605&expires=1611318907786&clientType=14&appId=512000384397&id=1868760950815&userId=0&vkOwnerId=-182332542&vkVideoId=456244886" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>Name: <input name="myTextField" value="Test"></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="myCheckBox"> Check</label>
  <label>Upload file: <input type="file" name="myFile" value="DJ жги.mp4"></label>
  <button>Send the file</button>
</form>  данный html работает c таким url

Comment: можешь показать пример как ты передаешь content-type

Comment: @Zen, вместо написания отдельного «ответа» (не являющегося ответом на вопрос), лучше было, нажав [edit], добавить фрагмент кода в данный ответ (с соответствующим пояснением).

Comment: и у тебя не загружается? у меня просто все получилось

Comment: Починили похоже